# Inflating activity with a fragment by using service

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, layout-inflater, window-managers

I'm creating a service and when a message is send to this service it will display a layout which I want to show using the windowmanager. This layout is a Constraintlayout containing a fragment and a few other views.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/file_manager_background_gradient"
    tools:context=".FileManagerActivity"
    tools:ignore="SmallSp,SpUsage">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/file_manager"
        android:layout_width="610dp"
        android:layout_height="512dp"
        android:background="@drawable/file_manager_view_background"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_layout"
            android:layout_width="148dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/file_manager_navigation_background_gradient"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_list_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/file_manager_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/navigation_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/file_manager_nav" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what i'm trying in the onCreate from the service class, i am adding the view to the window manager in a different method.

```
override fun onCreate() {

    windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

    windowParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        windowType,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )
    windowParams!!.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START

    layoutInflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    assert(layoutInflater != null)
    fileManagerLayout = layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.activity_file_manager, null) as ConstraintLayout
}
```

But i keep getting the following error messages.

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.test.service.filemanager.FileManagerService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3414)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.service.filemanager-DnxbxoOUn_-DG6jY9I_vdg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.service.filemanager-DnxbxoOUn_-DG6jY9I_vdg==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.test.service.filemanager-DnxbxoOUn_-DG6jY9I_vdg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.test.service.filemanager.FileManagerService.onCreate(FileManagerService.kt:87)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3404)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Any feedback or advice is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use `<fragment>` in a `View` you're manually adding to `WindowManager`, at least not without some considerable effort. The specific reason it's crashing there is because that `LayoutInflater` doesn't know about `<fragment>`s, and is trying to load it like a regular `View`.

Comment: @PankajKushwaha no i haven't. As Mike M. commented we cannot use a fragment in a view we are trying to manually add to WindowManager, at least not without some considerable effort. I have changed the build-up of my application to get the result i wanted.

Comment: android start support chathead by Bubbles API, please review it

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeM mentioned this is not possible at least not with considerable effort. We have reviewed our layout construction to get our desired result.